# Reading text file and get line with date values

Tags: c#, readfile

Is there an easy way to find lines that consist of date time.

So far I can read the textfile and my next step is to parse it, but before that I think I need some guidance before I proceed. Here is my current read script:

```
List<string> Temp = new List<string>();            
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\\Temp\\", "*.txt");

foreach (string files in filePaths)
{
    var fileStream = new FileStream(files, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        Temp.Add(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
    }
}

foreach (string i in Temp)
{
    if (i.Contains("Events"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);        
    }
}
```

Here is the sample text template that I need to parse generated from the tool.

```
"[Output]"
"[Events]"
"Time"  "Duration"  "Severity"  "Event" "Text1" "Text2"


"[Acquisition Settings_1]"
"Data Set"  "DataSet1"
"Data Stream"   "Data"


"[Scan Data (Pressures in Torr)]"
"Time"  "Scan"  "Mass 1"    "Mass 2"    "Mass 3"    
"10/25/2018 4:59:27 PM" 1   5.5816e-008 1.3141e-008 -1.6109e-010    
"10/25/2018 4:59:35 PM" 2   5.5484e-008 1.3403e-008 6.9720e-010 
"10/25/2018 4:59:41 PM" 3   5.5633e-008 1.3388e-008 8.8094e-011 
"10/25/2018 4:59:48 PM" 4   5.7289e-008 1.2343e-008 1.4095e-010 
"10/25/2018 4:59:54 PM" 5   5.2841e-008 1.3219e-008 7.5257e-010 

"10/25/2018 4:59:57 PM" "After Calibration due to marginal data of daily pm3 rga checking"  
"10/25/2018 5:49:51 PM" "RGA Base Pressure
Flat pallet (2018-10-25_011_a1a)"   
"10/25/2018 6:21:53 PM" "PM3 SiNFILL_27A
2018-10-25_011_A4A" 
"10/25/2018 9:51:29 PM" "IBE1 STEP
FULL TAPE
NO PRE-BAKE"    
"10/25/2018 9:58:48 PM" "IBE2 STEP
```

And here is my Aim or expected result is to get the line with datetime value:

```
"10/25/2018 4:59:27 PM" 1   5.5816e-008 1.3141e-008 -1.6109e-010    
"10/25/2018 4:59:35 PM" 2   5.5484e-008 1.3403e-008 6.9720e-010 
"10/25/2018 4:59:41 PM" 3   5.5633e-008 1.3388e-008 8.8094e-011 
"10/25/2018 4:59:48 PM" 4   5.7289e-008 1.2343e-008 1.4095e-010 
"10/25/2018 4:59:54 PM" 5   5.2841e-008 1.3219e-008 7.5257e-010
```

Any suggestion TIA.

Comment: (A) What does `streamReader.ReadToEnd()` do? (Check your assumptions by looking into the documentation for StreamReader.ReadToEnd / TextReader.ReadToEnd) (B). Look what methods the `System.IO.File` class provides (again, documentation for this class will give you an overview as well as details about the provided methods). Some might be helpful in simplifying your code. (C) For processing of individual lines, look into how you can detect datetime lines or when they start and end (you might do simple string comparisons/finds, or try leveraging string pattern matching with regular expressions)

Comment: seems if you split with (") char, you can get dateform string on string[1]. try/catch to parse as date. if it's success, store on temp whole line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably (tentatively) get away with something like this *Pattern*. It takes into consideration negative *Extended Notation* and also has the tabs in the original format (not shown in the example)

```
^""\d+/\d+/\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+ (AM|PM)""\s+-?\d+\s+\d+.?\d+e-\d+
```

<sub>**Note**: I am not going to write the regex explanation as it's too long.</sub>

**Example**

```
var pattern = @"^""\d+/\d+/\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+ (AM|PM)""\s+-?\d+\s+\d+.?\d+e-\d+";
var regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);

var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Temp", "*.txt");

var results = new List<string>();

foreach (var file in filePaths)
{
   var lines = File.ReadLines(@"D:\sample.txt").Where(x => regex.IsMatch(x));
   results.AddRange(lines);
}
```

However, to take this a step further you could do the following. This will put all the data parsed into a class.

**Given**

```
public class ScanData
{
   public DateTime Time { get; set; }
   public int Scan { get; set; }
   public decimal?[] MassResults  { get; set; }

   public static ScanData FromString(string data)
   {
      var split = data.Split('\t');

      decimal? Local(string value)
      {
         return decimal.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Float, null, out var output) ? output : (decimal?)null;
      }

      var scanData = new ScanData()
                     {
                        Time = DateTime.ParseExact(split[0].Trim('"'), "M/d/yyyy h:m:s tt", null),
                        Scan = int.Parse(split[1]),
                        MassResults = split.Skip(2).Select(Local).ToArray()
                     };

      return scanData;
   }

}
```

**Example**

```
var pattern = @"^""\d+/\d+/\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+ (AM|PM)""\s+-?\d+\s+\d+.?\d+e-\d+";
var regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);

var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Temp", "*.txt");

var results = new List<ScanData>();

foreach (var file in filePaths)
{
   var lines = File.ReadLines(@"D:\sample.txt")
                   .Where(x => regex.IsMatch(x))
                   .Select(x => ScanData.FromString(x));
   results.AddRange(lines);
}
```

Comment: Should I need to store it in string in the reading loop? I can't see any output from mine. Is it because I append them to list then loop it.

Comment: @Rockn'Roll hi, i am not totally sure what you are asking, however i have updated with an example more inline with what you are doing.

Comment: I tried your suggested code but the list returns me System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String].

Comment: and If I am going to loop the the temp it returns me nothing

Comment: can I give you the actual txt file? the text file size is 102mb. I just simplify my sample  content there to be fit in my question.

Comment: @Rockn'Roll might be easier to talk here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190410/helpforrocknroll